# Factorial equaling a polynomial

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Are there any positive integer solutions $(n,x)$ to the equation $(x)(x+1)=n!$ except $(2,1)$ and $(3,2)$?

If not (as I suspect is the case), how do you prove that?

In general, is there a way to approach the Diophantine equation $n!=P(x)$ where $P$ is a polynomial?

Comment: @Vincent Please stop suggesting trivial edits to old questions.  Every time a question is edited, it gets bumped to the front page.  You're flooding the front page with old questions, which is against recommendations for editing [old questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13289/edit-rejection-too-minor).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question was discussed on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39210/solve-in-positive-integers-nmm1), and the question is open.